# Integrating JSON API (Hood.ie) with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently trying to integrate hood.ie with React Native. The hoodie backend uses http://jsonapi.org/format/.

According to the spec "Clients MUST send all JSON API data in request documents with the header Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json without any media type parameters.", if this doesn't happen, the server will return a 415 error.

The main issue I'm facing is that `charset=utf-8` is added to the `Content-Type` header, but it only happens on Android (see this Open Github issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8237#issuecomment-295790510 )

As far as I can tell, this issue is related to the native portion of the code that performs the request because I've tracked the request deep down into `react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js` and it looks like the headers remain untouched when ReactNative calls `BatchedBridge.enqueueNativeCall(moduleID, methodID, args, onFail, onSuccess);`

Has someone faced this issue before? Is there a workaround to prevent android from adding this (I know that's the standard [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type], but JSON API doesn't like it, also it doesn't happen on iOS)?

Comment: what type of body are you sending to the server ?

Comment: The Hoodie client sends a JavaScript object, after this the `xhr` module stringifies it and the result is what is being sent.

Comment: can i see the code?

Comment: Sure, I just created this repo:
https://github.com/alterx/hoodie-react-native
To run it you'll also need follow this instructions to install and run hoodie: http://docs.hood.ie/en/latest/guides/quickstart.html

Comment: I'm also using ngrok to tunnel localhost:8080 and make it externally accessible. Once you get that running, you need to update line 12 in App.js

Comment: What i think is that you are using some image or any other thing which is not string type and the request is trying to convert into some type of string while the thing is binary or file type.

Comment: Definitely not sending anything else. I used Charles to inspect the request and the only change is that, on Android, `charset=utf-8` is added to the `Content-Type` header. Everything else is the same in the request.